# use group by and having in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

how we can use group by and having in android?
i want to use this query :

```
select sum(Quantity) from tbl1 group by name having id=lastid
```

and get result to use in other place of my project
i saw in one page for groupy by use this code:

```
return mDd.query(DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] {
    KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_TITLE,
    KEY_DATAS,
    KEY_BODY,
    KEY_DATE_TIME
},null,null,KEY_TITLE,null,null);
```

but i don t know what should i do for having and sum()!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `rawQuery` method of the [SQliteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29) class :

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase2.rawQuery(
    "select sum(Quantity) from tbl1 group by name having id=lastid", null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    //process cursor
}
```

Inspired from [Fetching a SQLite SUM in Java on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182831/fetching-a-sqlite-sum-in-java-on-android)